# Adding a library from maven

Tags: android

I have to use an external library in `android.Library`: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.makeramen%7Croundedimageview%7C2.0.1%7Caar

I am using Eclipse and I have to download the library and then copy it to the `libs` folder.

Which file I should download in that link?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like

> roundedimageview-2.0.1-javadoc.jar

or

> roundedimageview-2.0.1-sources.jar

are the libraries you are looking for.

To import: Eclipse workspace > right click your project > Properties > Java Build Path > Add Jars